# Hide linearlayout on webview scroll

Tags: android, webview, onscrolllistener

I have an app screen, where I have a webview, and a linear layout of buttons at the bottom of the screen. I have a scroll listener attached to the webview, which is giving me values when scrolled. What I really want to do, is gradually hide the bottom linear layout when scrolling down, and show when scrolling up, as seen in a fair few apps, but all the examples I can see are toolbars at the top of the screen.

I have tried a number of things, I have tried getting the height of the linear layout, and then on scrolling, move it in the y axis to hide and show, and this moved the buttons within but not the actual bar.

The main thing I tried, is when scrolling, decreasing the height of the bar and when it reaches 0 hiding it, and then showing it again, but this is squashing the buttons rather than scrolling them off the bottom of the screen without changing their size.

This is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
    android:background="#403152"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/facebookLink"
        android:src="@string/button1"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="openLink"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linkedinLink"
        android:src="@string/button2"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="openLink"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/twitterLink"
        android:src="@string/button3"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="openLink"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/instagramLink"
        android:src="@string/button4"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="openLink"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_overflow"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="showPopup"
        android:id="@+id/aboutoption"/>
</LinearLayout>


<holidays.ObservableWebView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableWebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonBar"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and then this is the code I have tried so far, which includes changing the height, etc - Hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong, or what may be a better way to tackle this.

```
mWebView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new ObservableWebView.OnScrollChangedCallback(){
                public void onScroll(int l, int t){

                    int height = mWebView.getMeasuredHeight();
                    Log.d("HEIGHT", Integer.toString(height));


                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int screenHeight = size.y;

                    Log.d("Screen HEIGHT", Integer.toString(screenHeight));


                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonBar);
                    View contentsView = findViewById(R.id.buttonBar);

                    if(firstScroll == true){

                        mWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(), mWebView.getMeasuredHeight() + 10));

                        /*originalButtonBarHeight = findViewById(R.id.buttonBar).getHeight();
                        currentButtonBarHeight = originalButtonBarHeight;

                        contentsView.getLocationOnScreen(screenBarPosition);
                        contentsView.setY(screenBarPosition[1] + 1);

                        firstScroll = false;
                        layout.getLayoutParams().height = t + 1;
                        layout.requestLayout();

                        directionVal = t;*/
                    }
                    else if(firstScroll == false){
                        if(directionVal < t){
                            mWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(), mWebView.getMeasuredHeight() + 10));
                           /* Log.d("DOWN", Integer.toString(t));
                            if(currentButtonBarHeight <= 0){
                                //do nothing
                            }
                            else{
                                currentButtonBarHeight = currentButtonBarHeight - 5;

                                if(currentButtonBarHeight <= 0){
                                    currentButtonBarHeight = 0;
                                    layout.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                                    layout.requestLayout();

                                    findViewById(R.id.buttonBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                else{


                                    contentsView.getLocationOnScreen(screenBarPosition);
                                    contentsView.setY(screenBarPosition[1] + 1);

                                    layout.getLayoutParams().height = currentButtonBarHeight;
                                    layout.requestLayout();
                                }

                            }
                            /*if(t + 5 < originalButtonBarHeight) {

                            }*/
                        }
                        else if(directionVal > t){
                            Log.d("UP", Integer.toString(currentButtonBarHeight));


                            /*decreasedAmount = t - 5;
                            if (decreasedAmount < originalButtonBarHeight){
                                layout.getLayoutParams().height = t - 5;
                                layout.requestLayout();
                            }*/

                        }

                        directionVal = t;
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one by `CustomWebView`:

**CustomWebView.java**:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setGestureDetector(GestureDetector gestureDetector) {
        this.gestureDetector = gestureDetector;
    }
}
```

**web_fragment.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    

   <com.customview.CustomWebView
            android:id="@+id/customWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true" />

   // Your other Linear layout

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomeGestureDetector** clss for Gesture Detection (I have added in Fragment):

```
private class CustomeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
            if(e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1) return false;
            else {
                try {
                    if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > 20 ) {
                            // Show Your Linear Layout

                        customWebView.invalidate();
                       return false;
                    }
                    else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > 20 ) {
                            // Hide Your Linear Layout

                        customWebView.invalidate();
                       return false;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    customWebView.invalidate();
                }
                return false;
            }


        }
    }
```

**WebFragment.java**:

```
private CustomWebView customWebView;

customWebView= (CustomWebView) view.findViewById(R.id.customWebView);

customWebView.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector()));
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: This just shows/hides though rather than gradually show/hide?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your root `view` as `CoordinatorLayout`.
2. Wrap your content into `NestedScrollView`.
3. Add following to your bottom `View`:

   `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior">`